# Do I need separate revocation certificates for each email address associated with a key?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, certificate-revocation, enigmail

I just created my first OpenPGP key with GnuPG + Thunderbird + Enigmail. The key is used for two email addresses. Now I created a revocation certificate. There is only on of the email addresses included in the filename of the revocation certificate.

Do I need a separate revocation certificate for each email address?

or

Can I use the created revocation certificate to revoke the key for all email address associated with the key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dedicated revocation certificate generated with `--gen-revoke` is created for the *primary key* and does not include any information on a given user ID, but when distributed will also indirectly revoke all user IDs and subkeys (as they're only valid together with the primary key).